# How to add group product to cart using rest Api magento2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, grouped-products

using API **/V1/carts/mine/items** I got the tutorials / blogs to add configurable, simple and bundle products to cart but how can we add grouped product using this api?

What should be the payload ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Authenticate and Obtain Access Token
2. Create a Cart

POST /V1/carts/mine

3. Add Product to Cart

POST /V1/carts/mine/items

**Jason Body**

{
"cartItem": {
"sku": "your_group_product_sku",
"qty": 1,
"quote_id": "your_cart_id"
}
}

4. Review Cart

GET /V1/carts/mine/items

Comment: @Parachi "message": "Please specify the quantity of product(s)."

Comment: Please mention quantity according your product

Comment: I got the issue in grouped product you need to individually add items to cart by mentioning the SKU of only childs products.

Comment: curl -X POST "https://your-magento-domain/rest/V1/carts/YOUR_CART_ID/items" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
        "cartItem": {
            "sku": "YOUR_SKU",
            "qty": YOUR_QTY,
            "quote_id": "YOUR_CART_ID",
            "product_option": {
                "extension_attributes": {
                    "group_id": YOUR_GROUP_ID
                }
            }
        }
    }'